# Div element gets weirdly resized while dragging and dropping, but it only happens ~3% of the time

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I can't for the life of me figure out the cause of this bug.

This is for a Chrome Extension I'm working on that simply displays an on-page timer for users when they're on a website they want to track time on.

In the content script, it creates the timer element like so:

```
function AddStickyTimer(i) {

  var parentElement = document.body;
  var timerElement = document.querySelector('#on-page-timer');
  
  if (!timerElement) { 
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a new div element that we'll add to the webpage
    const uniqueId = 'on-page-timer'; // set a unique ID
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', uniqueId);

    // Load position from Chrome storage
    chrome.storage.local.get(["TimerPosition" + (i+1), "TimeframePreference"], function(result) {

      // console.log(result["TimeframePreference"]);

      if (result["TimerPosition" + (i+1)]) {
        const position = JSON.parse(result["TimerPosition" + (i+1)]);
        newDiv.style.top = position.top;
        newDiv.style.left = position.left;
      } else {
        newDiv.style.top = "5vh";
        newDiv.style.right = "5vw";
      }

      // Set the style for the div // this is placed in here to avoid a glitchy flash that occurs when it first loads in the original spot, then moves to the updated one.
      newDiv.style.position = "fixed";
      newDiv.style.background = "white";
      newDiv.style.display = "none"; // defaults to not visible, then displays when the timer text is ready -- to avoid glitchy appearances with no text + then re-sizings that would happen
      newDiv.style.justifyContent = "center";
      newDiv.style.alignItems = "center";
      newDiv.style.paddingTop = "8px";
      newDiv.style.paddingBottom = "8px";
      newDiv.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
      newDiv.style.paddingRight = "10px";
      newDiv.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
      newDiv.style.color = "black";
      newDiv.style.zIndex = "999999";
      newDiv.style.fontSize = "17px";
      newDiv.style.borderWidth = "2px";
      newDiv.style.borderColor = "black";
      newDiv.style.borderStyle = "solid";
      newDiv.style.textAlign = "center";
      newDiv.style.cursor = "move";
      newDiv.style.width = "auto";
      newDiv.style.height = "auto";
      // newDiv.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap"; // this prevents some weird glitchy text spillover that would happen once the auto-generated height/width was locked in
      newDiv.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma, sans-serif";

    });

    // Add event listeners for dragging
    let isDragging = false;
    let startX;
    let startY;

    newDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // this prevents the "highlight a bunch of text and webpage content" behavior that would occur when repositioning the timer
      isDragging = true;
      startX = event.clientX - newDiv.offsetLeft;
      startY = event.clientY - newDiv.offsetTop;
    });

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        const left = (event.clientX - startX) / window.innerWidth * 100;
        const top = (event.clientY - startY) / window.innerHeight * 100;
    
        // Ensure the timer stays within the boundaries of the viewport
        const timerWidth = newDiv.offsetWidth;
        const timerHeight = newDiv.offsetHeight;
        const maxX = 100 - ((timerWidth + window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth) / window.innerWidth * 100); // This calculates the maximum X and Y values taking into account the width of the scrollbar, which is the difference between the window.innerWidth and the document.documentElement.clientWidth (the width of the viewport excluding the scrollbar). The same is done for the height of the scrollbar.
        const maxY = 100 - ((timerHeight + window.innerHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight) / window.innerHeight * 100); // This modification prevents the "timer being squashed vertically" bug I kept encountering when trying to reposition it via drag-and-drop
        const x = Math.max(0, Math.min(maxX, left));
        const y = Math.max(0, Math.min(maxY, top));      
    
        newDiv.style.left = x + "vw";
        newDiv.style.top = y + "vh";
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        const position = { top: newDiv.style.top, left: newDiv.style.left };
        chrome.storage.local.set({["TimerPosition" + (i+1)]: JSON.stringify(position)});
      }
      isDragging = false;
    });

    window.addEventListener('blur', function() { 
      // handles cases where the browser window loses focus while the user may be mid drag-and-drop
      // this helps avoid an occasional bug where the timer will get "stuck" to the mouse while dragging and dropping.
      if (isDragging) {
          const position = { top: newDiv.style.top, left: newDiv.style.left };
          chrome.storage.local.set({["TimerPosition" + (i+1)]: JSON.stringify(position)});
          isDragging = false;
      }
  });

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv); // Add the div to the document body
  }

}
```

And the next function that runs populates this timer element with the active timer for the given webpage:

```
function RunTimer(i) {

  TimerStatus = "timer is running";

  // console.log("TIMER STARTED");

  myInterval = setInterval(async function() {

    WaitingToCheckDates = await CheckDates();
    WaitingToCheckMonths = await CheckMonth();
    WaitingToCheckYears = await CheckYear();

    chrome.storage.local.get(["daily_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today", "monthly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today",
    "yearly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today", "URLtoTrack" + (i+1), 
    "DisplayTimerCheckboxSetting", "TimeframePreference"], function(result) {

      if (!(result["daily_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"])) {
        DailyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage = 0;
      } else {DailyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage = result["daily_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"]};
      
      if (!(result["monthly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"])) {
        MonthlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage = 0;
      } else {MonthlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage = result["monthly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"]};
  
      if (!(result["yearly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"])) {
        YearlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage = 0;
      } else {YearlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage = result["yearly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"]};
  
      CurrentURLToTrack = result["URLtoTrack" + (i+1)];

      DailyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage++; // the incrementation needs to be done up here, separate from the variable assignment below. otherwise, after resetting to 0, it would just hover there and not increment up.
      MonthlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage++;
      YearlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage++;

      UpdatedDailyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL = DailyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage;
      UpdatedMonthlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL = MonthlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage;
      UpdatedYearlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL = YearlyTimeSpentOnURLFromStorage;

      // console.log(UpdatedDailyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL);
      // console.log(UpdatedMonthlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL);
      // console.log(UpdatedYearlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL);

      var hours = Math.floor(UpdatedDailyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL / 3600);
      var minutes = Math.floor((UpdatedDailyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL % 3600) / 60);
      var ConstructedTimer1 = hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes";

      var hours2 = Math.floor(UpdatedMonthlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL / 3600);
      var minutes2 = Math.floor((UpdatedMonthlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL % 3600) / 60);
      var ConstructedTimer2 = hours2 + " hours " + minutes2 + " minutes";

      var hours3 = Math.floor(UpdatedYearlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL / 3600);
      var minutes3 = Math.floor((UpdatedYearlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL % 3600) / 60);
      var ConstructedTimer3 = hours3 + " hours " + minutes3 + " minutes";

      // the reason only THIS is conditional on display settings? 
      // Because the timer can still run + track these stats. Just won't display them now.
      if (result["DisplayTimerCheckboxSetting"] == "true" || result["DisplayTimerCheckboxSetting"] == undefined) {

        document.getElementById("on-page-timer").style.display = "flex"; // makes timer visible only when the text content is ready + inside of it

        if (result["TimeframePreference"] == "daily" || result["TimeframePreference"] == undefined) {
          document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted Today: <br>" + ConstructedTimer1 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack; // update the text content of the timer element
        }
        if (result["TimeframePreference"] == "monthly") {
          document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted This Month: <br>" + ConstructedTimer2 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack;
        }
        if (result["TimeframePreference"] == "yearly") {
          document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted This Year: <br>" + ConstructedTimer3 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack;
        }
        if (!(result["TimeframePreference"])) { // defaults to showing "time wasted today" if the timeframe preference isn't found in storage
          document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted Today: <br>" + ConstructedTimer1 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack;
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById("on-page-timer").style.display = "none";
      }

      chrome.storage.local.set({["daily_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"]: UpdatedDailyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL,
        ["monthly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"]: UpdatedMonthlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL,
        ["yearly_time_spent_on_url_" + (i+1) + "_today"]: UpdatedYearlyTimeSpentOnCurrentURL}, function() {});
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

The main thing I've tried is, "locking in" the auto-generated width and height after the text is added inside of the timer element. So basically, the width and height CSS would start as auto, then only after it's populated with text, it would switch to "locked in" , in the hopes that this would help prevent that weird resizing behavior:

```
function Lock_In_Auto_Generated_Timer_Width_and_Height() { // this "locks in" the auto-generated width and height, which dynamically vary based on text input
  
  document.getElementById("on-page-timer").style.display = "flex"; // makes timer visible only when the text content is ready + inside of it

  const timerElement = document.getElementById("on-page-timer"); // allows it to be optimally sized, and apparently eliminates that "resizing weirdly" bug I kept seeing when it was stuck on auto
  const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(timerElement);
  const timerWidth = computedStyle.width; 
  const timerHeight = computedStyle.height;
  timerElement.style.width = timerWidth;
  timerElement.style.height = timerHeight;
}
```

and that pertinent part of the StartTimer() function would look like this instead:

```
  if (result["DisplayTimerCheckboxSetting"] == "true" || result["DisplayTimerCheckboxSetting"] == undefined) {

document.getElementById("on-page-timer").style.width = "auto";
document.getElementById("on-page-timer").style.height = "auto";

if (result["TimeframePreference"] == "daily" || result["TimeframePreference"] == undefined) {
  document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted Today: <br>" + ConstructedTimer1 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack; // update the text content of the timer element
}
if (result["TimeframePreference"] == "monthly") {
  document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted This Month: <br>" + ConstructedTimer2 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack;
}
if (result["TimeframePreference"] == "yearly") {
  document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted This Year: <br>" + ConstructedTimer3 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack;
}
if (!(result["TimeframePreference"])) { // defaults to showing "time wasted today" if the timeframe preference isn't found in storage
  document.getElementById("on-page-timer").innerHTML = "Time Wasted Today: <br>" + ConstructedTimer1 + "<br>on " + CurrentURLToTrack;
}
  } else {
    document.getElementById("on-page-timer").style.display = "none";
  }

  Lock_In_Auto_Generated_Timer_Width_and_Height();
```

Now the reason for THIS approach is, I want the timer size to be able to dynamically update. That's because users might switch the timeframe they're tracking for which will modify the text inside, that's also because, it's hard to just "guess" what size is needed for the element and specify as an absolute size, since who knows how long the URL will be that the user inputs (and that will therefore pop up inside of the timer and potentially spill over and look bad if it's too long.) This fix did not work by the way, same issue appears.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this and what some potential solutions would be? Is this a known phenomenon with dragging and dropping div elements that'll sometimes happen? Is there something in my code that I've written which could be causing this?

Also note that the behavior seems to be more commonly observed when the timer is appearing for the first time on a new website that hasn't been visited in a long time, or ever. That's not the ONLY time it happens, but certain websites, it seems to be more prone to happening on than others.

Thanks!